# Can the Pukka 1-shot the Fool?

Tags: blood-on-the-clocktower

In [Blood on the Clocktower](https://bloodontheclocktower.com/), the [Fool](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Fool) is immune to their first death:

> The first time you die, you don't.

This ability, like all abilities, goes away if the character is drunk or poisoned.

The [Pukka](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Pukka)'s ability seems like it could potentially counteract the [Fool](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Fool):

> Each night, choose a player: they are poisoned until tomorrow night, then die. You act on the first night.

While the [Fool](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Fool) is poisoned, they are not immune to their first death. However, this wording of the [Pukka](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Pukka)'s ability (specifically the "they are poisoned **until** tomorrow night, **then** die") is unclear - "until" and "then" make me think that perhaps when the [Fool](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Fool) dies to the [Pukka](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Pukka), they are not **at that moment** poisoned, and therefore their ability would trigger to prevent that first death.

With no other interactions involved, can the [Pukka](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Pukka) kill the [Fool](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Fool) on their first attack?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it appears the fool can be killed without their ability working if targeted by the pukka

> If Pukka is in play, nobody is safe. The Fool and the Sailor can not be protected by their character ability etc. Also, since the Pukka chooses who to kill a full night earlier than normal, it is beneficial for all good players to reveal their characters and information to the group publicly as soon as possible. Sometimes, with other Demons, it can be beneficial for some good players to not reveal who they are, so that the Demon attacks certain players and leaves others alone - but with the Pukka, this is not the case. Reveal everything, and work as a team to bring that pesky poisoner to justice!